Apex Charts - uniform zoom
I'm using Blazor-ApexCharts nugget in dotnet 8 blazor wasm application, but i think this relates to any other application type.
Is there any way to zoom in on X and Y axis by the same factor?
The issue is that now, when zooming in the chart x=y changes from diagonal to almost horizontal line.
Let say that at the begining I have on X and Y axis values from 0 - 500. So after zoom in, I would like to see values ranging from 100 - 400 on either axis.

I tried setting following properties:

ForceNiceScale
TickAmount
StepSize
min and max
Chart.Width and Height
AxisType

Non of the above helped

I think you are looking for below configuration Type = AxisType.Xy, then you could "drag select" an area to zoom this area on both x and y axis. (click the "+" icon will still zoom the x axis anyway):
ApexChart TItem="DataPoint" Title="Sample Chart" Options="chartOptions">
    <ApexPointSeries TItem="DataPoint" Name="Series 1" Items="dataPoints" XValue="@(data => data.X)" YValue="@(data => data.Y)">
    </ApexPointSeries>
</ApexChart>

@code {
    private List<DataPoint> dataPoints = new List<DataPoint>
    {
        new DataPoint { X = "Category 1", Y = 10 },
        new DataPoint { X = "Category 2", Y = 20 },
        new DataPoint { X = "Category 3", Y = 30 },
        new DataPoint { X = "Category 4", Y = 40 },
        new DataPoint { X = "Category 5", Y = 50 },
    };

    private ApexChartOptions<DataPoint> chartOptions = new ApexChartOptions<DataPoint>
        {
            Chart = new Chart
            {
                Zoom = new Zoom
                {
                    Enabled = true,
                    Type = AxisType.Xy // Allows zooming on both X and Y axes
                }
            }
        };

    public class DataPoint
    {
        public string X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
    }
}


Setting AxisType to AxisType.Xy solves my issue just partialy. In case, I want to zoom 2 times on X and Y axis I would have to 'draw' the perfect square, which is impossible. And as you mentioned '+' and '-' buttons will only affect zoom on X axis.
